# AngularJS: Update array after submitting a new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to update an array after I save an object by replacing the `push` method. I tried to use a function instead of the `push` method but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix that?

```
app.controller("productController", function($scope, $http, createProductService, listProducstService){

    $scope.addProduct = function(){
        var newProduct = createProductService.createProduct($scope.product);
        //$scope.products.push(newProduct);     
        updateArray();
    };

    $scope.products = listProductsService.query();

    var updateArray = function(){
        $scope.products = listProductsService.query();
    }
}

app.factory("listProductsService", function($resource){
    return $resource("getAllProducts", {}, {
        listProducts: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you confirm your create call is working? The product is actually added on the server.

Comment: Yes. If I reload the page the new product is in the table, I can save the product but I can't show it after submit as the push() method.

Comment: `ListProduct's` query isn't in the code you've given us. Please include that or verify that it is an array, [array like objects](http://www.2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html) don't include the `push` method.

Comment: @DavidArchibald It does, the service is below, the query is into it.

Comment: I was under the impression that you had to define it like `query: ...` in the `listProducts` object.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$scope.$apply()` :

```
var updateArray = function(){
   $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.products = listProductsService.query();
   });    
}
```

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html